# Which is safer - using Firebase auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword() or using a cloud function?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm building a social media app with a focus on group chatting. I am working on creating a new user. Firestore provides this function to begin the process of creating the user from the client:

```
auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword
```

However, I read that it's safer to try to minimize what lives on the client side and do most of the app's work on the server side. Should I use the function above (on the client) or should I make a custom function that passes the email and password to the server and create the user there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, `auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword` is not a Firestore method.  It's a [Firebase Auth method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users).  Firestore is a database, Firebase Auth is an authentication service.  It's good not to mix up their responsibilities.

The options you're proposing are not, in practice, any different in terms of security.  That's because the Firebase Auth service provides a [public REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth) for creating new user accounts that's accessible to the world if you've enabled email and password authentication for your project.  It doesn't really matter if you invoke that from a frontend or backend - the net result is the same.

Do whatever you find most convenient.  Firebase Auth was designed so that users can create their own accounts using the authentication providers that you enabled.  Adding another backend service to that seems to just add more work for no extra benefit.